# Create Animation for Blender from Script

Tags: python, animation, blender

I need a script for Blender to create animations or animation keys. I have the time of the key, the change of position and rotation, and the path to the object that is animated by the key (like "Root > Left Arm > Left Hand" ).Is it possible to do this somehow using a table or an array or something else?